# Algebraic Curve of genus one and Complex Torus

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I am reading Rick Miranda's Book and he states

> Every algebraic curve of genus one is isomorphic to a complex torus. Now to do this let $X$ be our Riemann surface and we know that $\pi : Y\rightarrow X$, where $Y$ is the universal covering of $X$, and where $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ acts on $Y$ by two independent translations, and $Y=\mathbb{R^2}$ as a topological space, so all we need to see is that $Y\cong \mathbb{C}$ as a Riemann surface. Now for this we take a canonical divisor $K_0=div(w_0)$ in $X$ and we know that $deg(K_0)=0$ and $dimL(K_0)=1$ by Riemann-Roch and so we can take $f\in L(K_0)$ so that $w=fw_0$ will have no zeros and poles, since $deg(div(w))=0$ and $div(w)\geq 0.$ Now we can take $\pi^*(w)$ in $Y$ which will have no zeroes and will be a holomorphic $1$-form, and we fix a point $p_0$ and define $\phi:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as $\phi(p)=\int_{\gamma_p}\pi^*w$, where $\gamma_p$ is a path from $p_0$ to $p$, and this is well-defined since the integral will only depend on the end-points.

Now my question is how do we know that is surjective or even injective. I know it depends only on the endpoints but I don't see this giving us what we want, I can't seem to be able to prove it, and the author doesn't do it or even metion this so I dont know if this is just a trivial statement or not, he says he will return to it later but I haven't gotten to that part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained nicely in the book by Herbert Clemens, "A Scrapbook of Complex Curve Theory", Paragraph 2.9. It is not obvious at all, and involves an argument by Riemann.